# Is there any dev tool that show us where UI is re-rendered at Angular app

Tags: angular

I'm developing Angular(4+) apps and I want to know where UI is re-rendered by Angular.

I tried Augury but it does't provide that...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved.

I use Chrome DevTools「Rendering > Enable paint flashing」.

I didn't know this option...

Comment: For all wondering where that "Rendering" menu in DevTools is: Click the three dots next to the console tab.